# RStudio does not see packages being updated

Tags: r, rstudio, package, updates

After I run `install.packages('some_package')` and it is installed successfully RStudio asks me whether I want to update a list of old packages:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpu75mCG/downloaded_packages’
Old packages: 'acepack', 'base64', 'colorspace', 'DBI', 'digest', 'ggplot2', 'gridSVG', 'Hmisc', 'limma', 'plyr', 'Rcpp',
  'reshape2', 'R.oo', 'RSQLite', 'R.utils', 'scales', 'stringi', 'stringr', 'XML', 'abind', 'colorspace', 'crayon',
  'digest', 'ggplot2', 'gtable', 'mapproj', 'maps', 'memoise', 'munsell', 'pkgKitten', 'plyr', 'proto', 'Rcpp',
  'reshape2', 'scales', 'sp', 'stringi', 'stringr'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:
```

I say `a` and seem to have no errors but next time I install some package RStudio asks me to update the very same packages. I can successfully install single package `install.packages('acepack')` but RStudio still asks me to update it next time.

How to convince RStudio I have updated packages already?

Using R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21), RStudio version 1.0.143, Ubuntu 16.04

**Upd:**

The same when I do it in plain R.

The same when I run Bioconductor's `biocLite()` function

Comment: What is the output of `.libPaths()`? It might be the case that packages get installed in various locations and old versions persist in some of them.

Comment: Installed in various locations they were! Reducing locations amount solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, packages get stored in different folders, and when you update them, old versions may remain in some of them, causing these kind of issues.

Have a look at the output of `.libPaths()` and search these corresponding folders. There are many ways to prevent these conflicts from emerging, for instance by defining a fixed package repository in your `RPROFILE` file.